# Rails Set Code Alfhabet A-Z when inserting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to generate code A-Z for types Id when I insert the data.
I have a types_controller like this:

```
def new
 @type = Type.new(params[:type])
 @number = ('J%03d' % ((@types.last.code.split("J").last.to_i rescue 0)+1))
 @code = (('%03d' % ((Type.where("parent_id IS NOT NULL").last.code.to_i rescue 0)+1)))
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

the result above code are :
`@number` =`J001` , `J002`, .....
and `@code` = `001`, `002`,.....

How code, if I want to the result like this :

`@number` =`A` , `B`, `C` .....

and `@code` = `A001`, `A002`,..... when the `@number` = `A`

and `@code` = `B001`, `B002`,..... when the `@number` = `B`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of alphabet characters by doing ("A".."Z").to_a.

Comment: The results of above code are `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]` 
right?
But I want to the Result just one Alfhabet, for example :
when I insert first time the code should `A` , the second time `B` , the third time `C` etc until `Z`.

Comment: "B".next will return "C". So you can save the letter you're on somewhere, then when you need the next letter call next on it, use it and overwrite the variable.